# SDL2 not sending input events on OSX

Tags: macos, rendering, sdl, sdl-2, ogre

I'm trying to use SDL2 with Ogre on OSX and the rendering things work fine, but I'm not receiving any keyboard and mouse events.

For rendering loop, I use a `NSTimer` with `0.001s` interval.
If I do a `SDL_PumpEvents();` or `SDL_PollEvent(&event)` in my loop then I get *some* keyboard events but not perfectly and the mouse works fine.

What causes this weird behaviour?

Thanks!

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001
  target:self
  selector:@selector(step)
  userInfo:NULL repeats:YES];
[self.timer fire];

...

-(void) step {
  renderOneFrame();
  SDL_GL_SwapWindow(sdlWindow);

  SDL_PumpEvents();
  // or
  SDL_Event event;
  while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) { }
}
```

### Update

If I add `SDL_AddEventWatch(_eventFilter, this);` to listen for events mouse and other events (e.g. quit) works without polling or other things!
But still not receiving keyboard events.

Comment: Maybe you're checking incorrectly. What happens if you use GetKeyboardState and compare the keys?

Comment: First, I added some updates to the original question, and I checked with GetKeyboardState and without polling no key is recognized as pressed.